# How to pass errors back in responseText using C# / ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, exception

We have a C# AJAX server that handles database requests we want to return a 400/403/500 status code on an exception so that we can understand what went on at the client side.  However, all we get back is "Bad Request" in the response body.

For example, if the ADO.Net driver returns this message:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column '--COLUMN--', table
>   '--DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE--'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been terminated.

Then our AJAX Server simply returns this text:

> Bad Request

I have looked at the full response headers in Chrome and there is nothing even remotely resembling this error message in there.  This is the code we're using to send the error back:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.SC_BAD_REQUEST;
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

In the Java/JSP equivalent to this server we are getting the correct behavior with this code:

```
} catch (Exception e) {

    response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getClass() + " : " + e.getMessage());

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things that could be going wrong, but I'd be prepared to bet that you're running on IIS7 and its defaults are causing it to rewrite the error. Try the [TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx) property and the `existingResponse` attribute on the [httpErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) configuration setting.

Comment: Adding this to the web.config did the trick - many thanks! `<system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" existingResponse="PassThrough">
       </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>`

Answer (score 0):

The server is encapsulating the error message into a bad request to prevent secure details from reaching the client.  You can modify this behavior by setting the customErrors to off, e.g.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors> 
</system.web>
```

Comment: That affects which is chosen if something outside of ASP.NET raises an error, rather than those explicitly set, doesn't it?

Comment: I just changed this in web.config and it had no effect.